# Find the Frequency (I think?) of a Sinusoidal Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Given equation: $v = .96 \sin (\pi t/3.4)$, where $v$ is the velocity (in liters/sec) of airflow during a respiratory cycle and $t$ is the time in seconds.

I need to find the number of cycles per minutes, in units of cycles per min. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Usually we ask people to show more of their own efforts before we answer, but this time you have some "answers" that might help you get started with that effort. By the way, I formatted your equation using markup explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0):

Every time the input parameter of the sine function increases by $2\pi,$ the function goes through another cycle. So from $0$ to $2\pi$ is one cycle, from $0$ to $4\pi$ is two cycles, etc.

In $t$ seconds, the input parameter of the sine in your equation goes from $0$ to $\pi t/3.4.$
Set $t = 60$ and you have the change in the parameter over $60$ seconds.
So that gives you a number, and that number is $2\pi$ times the number of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Sinusoids follow the form $$a\sin(bx+c)$$

- $a$ is the amplitude, since $\sin$ naturally has amplitude $1$
- $2\pi/b$ is the period, since $\sin$ naturally has period $2\pi$ and multiplying $x$ by a constant greater than $1$ causes a horizontal compression
- $c$ tells you the phase shift

You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Recall that in $a\sin[b(x-h)]+k$, $b$ represents the number of cycles in the domain $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$ and $\frac{2\pi}{b}$ represents the period, or length of a single cycle.